# How do I mutate existing data with GraphQL, Graphene and Relay?

Tags: django, graphql, relay, graphene-python

I feel like it should be documented somewhere but I cant find it. I can add data to my db with a mutation but I cant change it.

Graphene works with Django and my db is SQLite

Its quite specific, I hope someone knows the answer. Among other things I tried:

```
mutation AppMutation(
  $input: AddSchoolNodeInput!
  ) {
    addSchool(input: $input) {
      school {
        id
        name
        description
     }     
    }
  }
```

where `AddSchoolNodeInput!` is (`"U2Nob29sTm9kZToxMQ=="` is an existing id):

```
{
  "name": "edit kaas", 
  "description": "edit fails",
  "clientMutationId":"U2Nob29sTm9kZToxMQ=="
 }
```

it create a new item and returns this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "addSchool": {
      "school": {
        "id": "U2Nob29sTm9kZToxNA==",
        "name": "edit kaas",
        "description": "edit fails"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to edit an existing school by providing the ID to the above mentioned mutation and doing this in the schema:

```
class AddSchool(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        name = String()
        description = String()
        id = String()

    school = Field(SchoolNode)

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, input, context, info):
        name = input.get("name")
        description = input.get("description")
        id = input.get("id")

        if id:
            id = from_global_id(id)[1]
            school = School.objects.get(id=id)
            if name:
                school.name = name
            if description:
                school.description = description

        else:
            school = School(
                name=name,
                description=description
            )

        school.save()

        return AddSchool(school=school)
```

It grabs the ID, puts it trough an if statement, transfers it from the graphene ID to the django ID with `from_global_id` and then grabs it from the db. If it can find it an error will occur, so no new school will be created, only if no id is provided.

Not sure if its best practice but it works.

Comment: I agree with you that documentation about mutations in general is lacking.

For this reason I have documented the way I do it here on this link: https://github.com/alexisrolland/flask-graphene-sqlalchemy/wiki/Flask-Graphene-SQLAlchemy-Tutorial#add-graphql-mutations

I’m not sure if that’s a good way to do mutations but it works for me too.

Comment: what if I want to do `if (Flase): return {"message": "you can't do this requiest"}` ? can I se `JsonResponse`?